# How to float text at the bottom of the list item space?

Tags: html, css

How to float text at the bottom of the list item space? 
I am trying to make all text in li stand at the bottom of the li height. Is there any better way to achieve that look?
And how to hyperlink an h1 header?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.menu ul {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.menu ul li {
  height: 110px;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
  padding-left: 18px;
  padding-right: 18px;
  margin-top: 110px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><img src="{% static 'images/logo-01.png' %}" width="120px" height="120px"></li>
    <li>
      <a class="header" href="#">
        <h1>Sitename</h1>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">option1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">option4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to do minor changes to your `CSS`. I have added `display: flex;` and `align-items: flex-end;`

Since flexbox is a whole module and not a single property, it involves a lot of things including its whole set of properties. Some of them are meant to be set on the container (parent element, known as "flex container") whereas the others are meant to be set on the children (said "flex items").

You can learn more about the flexbox layout from the below link.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  nav{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
  }

   .menu ul{
    margin-left: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
  }


  .menu ul li {
    list-style: none; 
  }
  
  .menu ul li img {
    display: block;
  }
  .menu ul li h1 {
    line-height: 1;
  }
  .menu ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI';
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 18px;
    color: black;
  }
  .menu ul li:hover a {
    color: red;
  }
  .menu ul li:hover h1 {
    color: black;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>
 <nav class="menu">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><img src="http://placehold.jp/120x120.png" width="120px" height="120px"></li>           
            <li><a class="header" href="#"><h1>Sitename</h1></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">option1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">option2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">option3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">option4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: that works. But there is a small difference between h1 bottom and a bottom space. How to fix that? h1 is not touching the line like a.

Comment: @KapishM Try setting the `line-height` property to something like 0.8

Comment: @DannyThanks! And what can I do for h1 to not follow a's properties. H1 is behaving like a, on hover, but with a big font.

Comment: If you add a background color to hover, it still shows on h1.

Comment: @KapishM I have added style `.menu ul li:hover h1` where you can overnight every properties on hover.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a parent div, and then wrap all the `li` in another div.

Set the parent div as `position: relative`, then the child div to:

```
position: absolute; 
bottom: 0;
```