# Can't align the unordered list in nav to the bottom using align-item:flex end

Tags: html, css

I am new to `CSS` and I wanted to align the navbar to the bottom of the magenta border by using `flex` and `align-items:flex-end`, but I can't seem to solve the problem.

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid magenta;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  align-self: center;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Living Social Life</h1>
      <p>A blog exploring minimalism in life</p>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Recent Posts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Share your code {`html`,`css`}

Comment: I hope [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59475256/how-to-float-text-at-the-bottom-of-the-list-item-space/59475334#59475334) solves your problem.

Comment: Hi @Pedram I have edited the question and added my html code

Comment: @SheharyarAnwar Not enough, still need to see `css` code! share it too

Comment: @Pedram I have added css too

Comment: @SheharyarAnwar Check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

can you share also the html code. but just looking at you css code this could be a solution:

HTML:

```
<ul class="flex-container nav">
  <li class="flex-item">Home</li>
  <li class="flex-item">About Me</li>
  <li class="flex-item">Recent Posts</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
.nav{
  flex-direction: column; 
  float: left;
}
.flex-item {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px;

  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `align-self: center;` from `nav` , it fix your issue:

```css
.container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid magenta;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="title">
      <h1>Living Social Life</h1>
      <p>A blog exploring minimalism in life</p>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Recent Posts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```